# Dropdown menu hides behind other elements in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I have installed the Boldy theme from site5 on one of my projects and have run into one major problem.

**When browsing in internet explorer (8 or lower), the top dropdown menu gets displayed behind some other elements (main content slider, H1's etc.).** I've tried everything from changing all the z-index's to fixed positions, with no luck.

You can view the problem by visiting site5's Boldy demo page http://wordpress.site5.net/boldy/ and hovering over the top menu's blog tab in IE.

I have asked site5 to look into it, they are aware of the problem, but have failed to find any solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Ok originale solution here - [Swiss credit website](http://www.chkredit.ch/). This works but uses a complicated z-index solution.
Here is very simple and improved solution here - [Jeyjoo stock image gallery](http://www.jeyjoo.com/gallery/)
This works in IE6+, firefox, opera, safari and chrome

**Solution**

**The HTML**

```
<div id="container_page" class="container_page">
  <div id="container_header" class="container_header">
    NAV BAR GOES HERE
  </div>
  <div id="container_body" class="container_body">
    ...body text...
  </div>
</div>
```

**The CSS**

```
#container_page #container_header {position:relative;z-index:2;}
#container_page #container_body {position:relative;}
```

**why it works**

You have to tell IE how the two divs relate to one another.

Comment: i would just like to tell people that i hate ie 8, thank you though , i really needed that, i had no idea what was going on

Answer (score 2):

(not my script) Pretty sure i may have found the answer to this on here, but i cant find it. Either way, this worked great for me...

```
$(function() {
var zIndexNumber = 1000;
$('ul').each(function() {
    $(this).css('zIndex', zIndexNumber);
    zIndexNumber -= 10;
});
});
```

just make sure your css includes `position` and `z-index` so the script can access the values.

kudos to whomever came up with this - saved me a whole lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, IE is not properly inheriting the z-index from the top-nav for the children li items in the menu. That is why the Photos with a z-index of 60 are covering it up. You can do two things here.

1. Eliminate the photo z-index.
2. Directly specify a z-index of 100 for the sub list, not just the top-nav list.

Answer (score 0):

I see you still havent solved this on.
I found a solution here on a submenu - [Chkredit - swiss credit website](http://www.chkredit.ch/)
Works in all versions of IE and is light and 100% CSS (no javascript).

Basically the problem was that IE does not use z-index correctly.
Check the z-index's in the CSS code. Yo will need to put a z-index -1 on the items your menu is hiding behind.

I working on exactly the same problem for my own image gallery right now (go to "top image" page) - [jeyjoo image gallery](http://www.jeyjoo.com/gallery/)