# Order in Internet Explorer

Tags: z-index

I've created a menu for a mobile site, when you click the menu button the menu slides opend, this is the page;

The only problem is that in IE and Windows phone the menu is not the top-most element so slides behind objects.

I have tried to change the z-index, position type, hasLayout to no avail.

I would appreciate any assistance.

J

Comment: Here we go, another "something is not working on IE"... Why I am not surprised? Anyway, try setting an absolute position for it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdown menu hides behind other elements in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3972807/dropdown-menu-hides-behind-other-elements-in-ie)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like you might be dealing with a known bug:

***“In Internet Explorer positioned elements generate a new stacking context, starting with a z-index value of 0. Therefore z-index doesn’t work correctly.”***

You can see the bug report on [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html) website and a workaround explained [in **this blog post**](https://www.brenelz.com/posts/squash-your-zindex-bugs).

Essentially what you have to do is wrap it in an element with higher Z-index, for example
Here is a quick sketch of a workaround:

```
<div style="position: relative; z-index: 3000">
    <div style="position:absolute;z-index:1000;">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Had the same problem and following the instructions on the link you posted solved it.

Comment: same, had this come up on an HTA file I have forced into IE7 and was getting frustrated with it so much.

Comment: You are the best !!

Answer (score 1):

I regularly swap two layers, changing the z-Index from 0 to 1, and visa-versa. After years, it stopped working in IE. I changed the z-Index to 1 and 2. It now works fine. I think the bug has to do with a 0 z-Index.