# How to position a link over another div that has position:absolute

Tags: html, css, position, css-position, absolute

I have the following HTML and CSS where the position of the `#header id` has to be mandatory set to `absolute`:

```
<div class="main">
    <a href="www.website.com">
    <div id="header" class="other">
</div>


#header{
    padding-left: 250px; 
    position:absolute;
}
```

This code sets the `header` div over the link tag and it becomes (the link) unavailable for selecting.

My question is what CSS do I have to apply to `.main > a` so that it does not get below the `header` div?

I tried the below but it does not work so any other ideas are welcomed:

```
.main > a {
    z-index:99999;  
}
```

Comment: try adding `position:relative` to `.main > a`..ie, your new CSS would be like  `.main > a {
    z-index:99999; position:relative;
}`

Comment: so simple...thanks mate!

Comment: Oh great...could you please mark my answer as accepted if that really helped you..

Comment: yes, I will, it will allow me to do so in 10 min. In the mean time, do you know why this is only working for Mozilla but in IE 10, the `a` tag is still unavailable?

Comment: Thankyou..please see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12517272/3168859) for the bug in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **`z-index` will work only on positioned elements**

`z-index` wont be applied if no positioning has been specified for the element. So, I would suggest you to change your CSS slightly as below.

ie, the new CSS for `.main > a` would be like

```
.main > a {
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999;  
}
```

**UPDATE**

`z-index` will not work with statically positioned elements..see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8486532/3168859)

Comment: What about `position: static;`? It will make the element to have a position specified, but `z-index` won't apply.

Answer (score 1):

The `z-index` attribute won't have effect if you don't set `position` to `relative`, `absolute` or `fixed`.

```
.main > a {
    position: relative;
    z-index:99999;  
}
```